# Attempting to search and replace a few lines in an XML file in every user's appdata/roaming folder

Tags: windows, powershell

I'm still kind of new to windows administration and very new to powershell so please forgive my ignorance. I wrote the following one-liner and I'm attempting to adapt it so that it can modify every existing user's FTRSettings.xml file on a PC. I'm worried that using the following path with a wildcard in place of the username would only replace the first file it finds.

```
C:\users\*\appdata\Roaming\FTR\GoldMain\FTRSettings.xml
```

Tested and working one liner executed from the appdata\Roaming\FTR\GoldMain\ directory.

```
((Get-Content -Path .\FTRSettings.xml -Raw) -replace '<Setting name="audioLevelsVisible" type="11">0</Setting>','<Setting name="audioLevelsVisible" type="11">-1</Setting>' -replace '<Setting name="inputLevelsVisible" type="11">0</Setting>','<Setting name="inputLevelsVisible" type="11">-1</Setting>' -replace '<Setting name="logSheetPaneViewState" type="11">0</Setting>','<Setting name="logSheetPaneViewState" type="11">-1</Setting>')
```

I was wondering if anyone could point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To process each file individually:

- Use [`Get-ChildItem`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-childitem) with your wildcard-based path to find all matching files.
- Loop over all matching files with [`ForEach-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/foreach-object) and perform the string replacement and updating for each file.

Note: I'm using a single `-replace` operation for brevity.

```
Get-ChildItem -Path C:\users\*\appdata\Roaming\FTR\GoldMain\FTRSettings.xml | 
  ForEach-Object {
    $file = $_
    ($file | Get-Content -Raw) -replace 'foo', 'bar' |
      Set-Content -Encoding utf8 -LiteralPath $file.FullName -WhatIf
  }
```

<sup>Note: The [`-WhatIf` common parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_commonparameters#whatif) in the command above *previews* the operation. Remove `-WhatIf`  once you're sure the operation will do what you want.</sup>

Note the use of `-Encoding` to control the character encoding explicitly, because the original encoding is never preserved in PowerShell; instead, the cmdlet's own default applies - adjust as needed.

Comment: wow! thanks so much! I've been toying with Get-ChildItem most of the day and haven't had much success. The only part that isn't clear to me is what $_ is doing in the above expression.

Comment: Glad to hear it, @Stag; Re `$_`: Oops! That was a conceptual flaw: The `Set-Content` call needs to reference `$_` as seen by `ForEach-Object`, not as seen inside the `Get-Content ... | SetContent ...` pipeline. Therefore, an aux. variable is needed - please see my update.